# How to run a command using bash alias which prompt for yes/no to proceed

Tags: bash, alias, sudo

I have created an alias sudo with the help of function to bypass manual password typing on stdin. Changes in sudoers file is something I am not allowed to do.

```
myfunction() {
if [ $1 == vi ] 
then
/usr/bin/sudo $*
else
echo "Password@123" | /usr/bin/sudo -S $*
fi
}
alias sudo=myfunction
```

It works fine until I run command which requires input from stdin but here I am not able to enter input yes or no.

```
sudo apt-get remove wicd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wicd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 47.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Abort.
```

Any solution which can make my alias to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo -v` ("validate") to do the password validation, then as long as you run additional `sudo` commands within 5 minutes it won't prompt for the password. BTW, you should use `"$@"` instead of `$*` in case any parameters contain spaces, wildcards, or other things that an unquoted reference might get confused by.

```
myfunction() {
    echo "Password@123" | /usr/bin/sudo -S -v
    /usr/bin/sudo "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I want to try. I could use -y with apt-get command and  this caching timing for sudo is already thete but I need something inside a function for alias.

Comment: @Bharat I'm not sure what you mean; this is a function, and you could easily add an alias to it (`alias sudo=myfunction`). You could also simply skip the alias and name the function `sudo`.